# Test ionic app on an actual device or emulator using visual studio code and android studio

Tags: cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I am a newbie with ionic app development and I build an ionic application and it works well on the browser everytime I run a test. Now, I am trying to run my ionic application to an actual device or an emulator using the command 'ionic cordova run android' but I always get this error

https://discourse-cdn-sjc1.com/ionicframework/uploads/default/original/3X/c/e/ce18e83cfea95dd322ce80cdcf3f11b5911f4eae.png

**Ionic CLI version:** PRO 4.2.1
**Cordova version:** 8.0.0
**NPM version:** 6.4.1
**Node.js version:** 8.11.3
**Visual Studio Code version:** 1.30.2
**Android Studio version:** 3.3
**Java version:** 1.8.0_191

I have also tried the following tutorials but I always get the same problem.
https://geeklearning.io/live-debug-your-cordova-ionic-application-with-visual-studio-code/
https://moduscreate.com/blog/ionic-cordova-debug-device-visual-studio-code/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWrKakQOCYE

I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like a problem with your android-sdk installation. Have you tried running your app with android studio? You should open the platforms/android folder as a project with android studio and try running from there

Comment: Yeah, I tried to open my platforms/android on android studio but I am not able to run it because the 'run' button was disabled and I don't even know why.

Comment: then try going to the sdk manager and update the android-sdk. Then make sure you have everything properly configured as it should. Check this link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the tip, I will try this and let you know the result :)

Comment: Hello @NicolásLonghi, I tried your suggestion but sadly it still doesn't work. The 'run' button is still disabled and even if I try to run it to the command panel it still returns the same error :(.

Comment: It looks like a problem with your android-sdk installation.
Like another user said, try setting the environment variables, try running `cordova clean` on your project, or delete the platforms folder all together and try again.
If nothing works try removing your android-sdk and installing it again following cordova guides.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I already fix the problem from the solution I got here (https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/test-ionic-app-to-actual-device-or-emulator/153300/2). Thank you so much anyways for your effort ❤

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe plugin dependency problem. Remove this cordova-plugin-firebase
>   plugin, then use this command on CLI:
>
> ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase cordova clean ionic
>   cordova prepare android ionic cordova run android I hope solve your
>   problem.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/test-ionic-app-to-actual-device-or-emulator/153300/2

Answer (score 0):

Check your environment variables after you've verified you have android SDK installed. Run the command `ionic cordova requirements`

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-environment-variables

Set them and restart your computer and try building again.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I already fix the problem from the solution I got here (https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/test-ionic-app-to-actual-device-or-emulator/153300/2). Thank you so much anyways for your effort ❤